# Sufficient conditions to show $f(x) \geq \min(f(0), f(1))$

Tags: functions, derivatives, convex-analysis

What are some sufficient conditions to show $f(x) \geq \min(f(0), f(1))$ for a smooth function $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$?

Which of those are also necessary?

Some ideas:

- $f$ is concave, i.e. $f''(x) \leq 0$ $\forall x$
- $f$ is monotonous, i.e. $f'(x) \leq 0$ or $f'(x) \geq 0$ $\forall x$
- $f$ is increasing then decreasing, i.e. $\exists a$ s.t. $f'(x) \geq 0$ $\forall x \leq a$ and $f'(x) \leq 0$ $\forall x \geq a$

(none of those is necessary)

Comment: You can have arbitrary “wild” functions with $f(x) \ge f(0)$, they need not be increasing, decreasing, concave, ... on any interval. What kind of necessary condition are you looking for?

Comment: A saw-tooth function shows that none of those conditoins is necessary.

Comment: You can say the integral of $f$ is larger than $\min (f(0), f(1))$.

Comment: $f''(x) < f'(x)$ is a sufficient condition.

Comment: @jMdA: I don't think this is sufficient.

Comment: @MartinR: what is the reasoning behind $f''(x)<f'(x)$ being sufficient?

Comment: @doc: $f$ cannot have attain its minimum at a point $c$ in the interior of the interval: $0 \le f''(c) < f'(c) = 0$ gives a contradiction.

Comment: What about: either $\int_0^x f(t)dt -f(0)x \geqslant 0$ or $\int_x^1 f(t)dt -f(1)(1-x) \geqslant 0$, for all $x \in [0,1]$. If I haven't screwed up, it should be a direct translation of the requirement.